# Spring JDBC - Retriable Exceptions for Kafka Consumer

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

I am using a Spring Kafka consumer to read messages off Kafka topic. I am persisting these in Oracle DB. Whenever there is a DB connection error , I want to perform a retry.I am using Spring JDBC to connect to oracle DB.What are the list of exception classes that I need to add in case if I need perform retry only JDBC connection issues.

```
private static Map<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean> retryableExceptions;

static{
    retryableExceptions = new HashMap<>();
    retryableExceptions.put(Exception.class, true);
}
protected RetryPolicy retryPolicy() {
        SimpleRetryPolicy policy = new SimpleRetryPolicy(maxRetryAttempts, retryableExceptions);
        return policy;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need just only this one:

```
/**
 * Data access exception thrown when a resource fails completely:
 * for example, if we can't connect to a database using JDBC.
 *
 * @author Rod Johnson
 * @author Thomas Risberg
 */
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DataAccessResourceFailureException extends NonTransientDataAccessResourceException {
```

As long as you use `JdbcTemplate` to perform JDBC operation, any low level error with the connection are wrapped to this `DataAccessResourceFailureException` or its subclasses.